# iOS rounded UITextField with shadow

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add a shadow effect to my UITextField currently what I'm achieving is this:
[image]

As you can see the shadow is not rounded in the corners. My code:

```
        mNickname.layer.borderWidth = 1
        mNickname.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        mNickname.layer.cornerRadius = 3

        mNickname.layer.masksToBounds = false
        mNickname.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        mNickname.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        mNickname.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)
        mNickname.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

Comment: remove borderColor and borderWidth

Comment: When I remove them the textField is no longer rounded.

Comment: did you removed cornerRadius as well?

Comment: No, because I want my textField to be rounded.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
Turns out that I was using
rectangle border:

[image]

The correct one should be:

[image]

And the code is:

```
mNickname.layer.masksToBounds = false
mNickname.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
mNickname.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
mNickname.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)
mNickname.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this, code is in objective C, but same for swift

```
self.textField.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    self.textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    self.textField.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UITextField {

    func addShadowToTextField(color: UIColor = UIColor.gray, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
   }
}
```

Add Extension and Usage:

```
    dateTxtFld.addShadowToTextField(cornerRadius: 3)
    dateTxtFld.addShadowToTextField(color: UIColor.blackColor, cornerRadius: 3)
```

Comment: backgroundColor is a key

Comment: Yes, backgroundColor of textfield is key, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change shadowOpacity to 0.5
Also, could you send full customisation of this textField?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension

```
extension ViewController {
    func setShadow(_ view: UIView) {
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false;
        view.layer.shadowRadius  = 3.0;
        view.layer.shadowColor   = UIColor.black.cgColor;
        view.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 4.0);
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you tried this
mNickname.layer.masksToBounds = true;

Comment: When I set it to true, the shadow is not visible anymore.