# Custom Border for textfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am new to iOS development with Swift. I want my textfield to look like the one below
[image]

I would like to know how to make a textfield look exactly like the one in the image

Comment: you add borderColor and ShadowBorder atteibutes to the TextField object instance...

Comment: it's normal textField with placeholder = "Your Name"

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the UITextField's layer property to add shadow.

Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35341894/5032154